# CHECK (length(to_char(nif, 'FM999MI')) = 9))

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with a column nif which has to be exactly 9 digits long, after I tried to do:

```
CREATE TABLE fornecedor(
    nif numeric(9) PRIMARY KEY,
    nome varchar(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT nif_tamanho CHECK (length(to_char(nif, 'FM999MI')) = 9)); 

INSERT INTO fornecedor(nif, nome) VALUES (123456789, 'Pmsmm');
```

It returns an error saying:

ERROR: new row for relation "fornecedor" violates check constraint "nif_tamanho"

How do I make it so that the inserted number is verified having 9 digits exactly ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `check (nif >=100000000)`?

Comment: I wanted to consider numbers with 012345678, is there a way ?

Comment: You can't store leading zeros, this is a display task.

Comment: If you try to store 012345678 in your nif column it will remove the 0.  If you need to store leading 0 and not have them cut off them you need to store the number as a string or you will have to repad the number.

Comment: Thanks @indiri and dnoeth for the help, I'm gonna talk with my teacher about the fact that I can't have leading 0's and see if I can either store this as a string or consider that this column which stores a numeric type has to begin with a first number bigger the 0 to avoid leading 0's. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mention in your comment, you need a string data type if you don't want to lose leading zeroes.

But I think that the correct solution depends on how you want to use the column. It is always good to choose the data type according to the column's semantics.

If you need to do arithmetic or numeric comparisons with the data, choose `integer` by all means (you can add a check constraint on `nif < 100000000`). You can always format the value with leading zeroes when you convert it to a string for output.

If you need to do string operations on the value (e.g. substrings), storing the data as a sting type is preferable.

Comment: Thank you very much, one thing is certain, lesson learned, no leading zeroes. Right now I have that part covered and I moved on to making other tables that I have to do, but I considered that the numbers I want to store don't have leading zeroes. Thank you for the help :)